# Rails is ignoring my filter definition in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

In rails 2.3.8 I'm trying to get a basic before_filter working. It works if I do these things in individual controllers, but now I want to do this in my ApplicationController.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

   before_filter :hello

private

   def hello
      puts "HELLO!"
   end

end
```

I'm expecting this to cause it run hello before running *any* of my controller actions, without the need to reference filters at all in my other controller classes. But it seems to just ignore it (never calling 'hello')  Why might that be?

Comment: Why do you think filter isn't invoked? Just for testing place some redirection in filter or post entire code of filter

Comment: Well I did wonder if I was just not seeing the "HELLO!" output (expecting it in the terminal where webrick is running), so I added a line to throw an error too, but... nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All other controllers should inherit from ApplicationController so for example:

```
class MyOtherController < ApplicationController
```

Only the ApplicationController should inherit from ActionController::Base

Rails was ignoring my before filter because I'd declared my other controller to be also inheriting from ActionController::Base.

At least I thought this was clear, but reading this [Action Controller Overview guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), it gives examples (some of the time) of other controllers inheriting from ActionController::Base . So that's confusing. In any case it fixes my problem if I always inherit from ActionController

Answer (score 0):

I know this won't help you, but your code is correct and works when I tested it, though on Rails 3.